# Contract size in brownie

Tags: brownie

What is the best way to get a contract size in Brownie?

Looking at the json in `build/contract`, I can see `deployedBytecode`. Is this what must be constrained in the 24k main net limit?

Answer (score 1):

Just enter "brownie compile --size" in your terminal